# Spinnaker setup on private Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Trying to setup Spinnaker on private Kubernetes cluster.
Can see the GUI but applications are not loading and throwing the below error.

> Error fetching applications. Check that your gate endpoint is
>   accessible. Further information on troubleshooting this error is
>   available here.

Getting Service Unavailable error on accessing the Gate URI.

I did edit gate and deck URI as follows. But still unable to access gate URI.

```
hal config security ui edit --override-base-url http://spin-deck.spinnaker-demo.com:9000

hal config security api edit --override-base-url http://spin-gate.spinnaker-demo.com:8084
```

When I tried describe pod for gate, getting the below error. Not sure, how to fix that.

> Readiness probe failed: wget: can't connect to remote host
>   (127.0.0.1): Connection refused

Front50 pod also has the below error.

> Readiness probe failed: wget: can't connect to remote host
>   (127.0.0.1): Connection refused

Broker console logs shows the below.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://spin-gate.test.com:8084/applications'
>   from origin
>   'http://spin-deck.test.com:9000' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
>   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

In Browser dev mode, under network,

> Request URL: http://spin-gate.test.com:8084/applications Request
>   Method: OPTIONS Status Code: 503 Service Unavailable

I checked the gate logs and it takes more than 2 mins to start spinnaker gate. Also, after starting the service, it throws error.

```
2019-08-06 09:07:54.035  WARN 1 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [com/netflix/spinnaker/gate/config/GateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
2019-08-06 09:07:54.430  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-08-06 09:07:54.631  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-2] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [pool-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-08-06 09:07:54.631  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-2] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [spectator-gauge-polling-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
 java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-08-06 09:07:55.034  INFO 1 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-08-06 09:07:55.336 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer' defined in class path resource [com/netflix/spinnaker/gate/config/GateConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder$run$0.call(Unknown Source) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at com.netflix.spinnaker.gate.Main.main(Main.groovy:53) [gate-web-4.35.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:4.35.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:204) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:348) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration$EnableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:249) ~[spring-session-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:226) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:16) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:888) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:432) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361) ~[commons-pool2-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184) ~[jedis-2.9.0.jar:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Is there anyway to fix these errors?

Comment: Can you try to open spinnaker url in the browser and check the network calls in developer mode. Want to check the api call where its failing. Also are you using any sort of authentication for spinnaker like basic auth, ldap, saml etc ?

Comment: No auth for spinnaker GUI. Have updated question with the browser dev mode.

Comment: Can you sepcify host as 0.0.0.0 in gate.yml and deck.yml `echo "host: 0.0.0.0" | tee ~/.hal/default/service-settings/gate.yml ~/.hal/default/service-settings/deck.yml` and `hal deploy apply`

Comment: I already have that. Checked the gate logs and it fails to start with the error. Redis is running fine. Do I need to create a network policy to connect to redis from gate. Updated question with the trace.

Comment: It works fine after adding the network policy for pod to pod communication.

Comment: Great! You can put that as answer, so anyone else can find it.

Comment: @user1578872 I'm facing a similar issue after running through issues with weave, deleted weave daemon sets and replaced with calico. Then getting the same error. do you remember exactly what needs to be done. Else I'll just create from scratch